# Not able to find "SelectedIndex" property of DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, selectedindex, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am new to windows forms application development.

I am using an editable grid view for data entry.

One of the fields in the grid view is of type ComboBoxColumn. I am filling the data in code.

My problem is if data item count is greater than 0 then first item should be selected automatically.

My code from `Page_Load()`  is:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Study\sem 6\Practice\WindowsFormsApplication1\Practice.accdb");
    cn.Open();
    cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from Grade", cn);
    da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    cn.Close();
}

private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell cmb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1]);
    cmb.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    cmb.DisplayMember = "Grd";
    cmb.ValueMember = "ID";

    if(cmb.Items.Count > 0)
    // Here I am not finding the the combo box's SelectedIndex Property.
}
```

Please help to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: cmb.SelectedItem. Are you looking for this?

Comment: Yes but I am finding neither `cmb.SelectedItem` nor `cmb.SelectedIndex` @FaisalHafeez

Comment: cmb.Value or cmb.DisplayMember.

Comment: @RiyazKalva Have you tried casting it to a regular combobox:
`(ComboBox)(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1]);`  ?

Comment: @RiyazKalva Ok. try handeling the `DataGridView.EditingControlShowing` event as suggested [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/be964ef4-daf9-4c5b-8e5a-08bd9d5ad3f9/)

Comment: Sir, Will you provide the full code plz?? @JensKloster

Comment: Sir,I tried the code from your suggested link but I am getting error @JensKloster

Comment: I tried the both but not working @FaisalHafeez

Comment: @RiyazKalva could you specify the error?

Comment: MSDN documentation says what I have told you.

Answer (score 0):

The class `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` does not have those properties. Look in the [documentaion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcell.aspx)

[Others](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/be964ef4-daf9-4c5b-8e5a-08bd9d5ad3f9/) have tried a different approach. In you code it would look somethink like this:

```
    private ComboBox _chashedComboBox;

    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing()
    {
       _chashedComboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
            var cmb = _chashedComboBox;
            if(cmb != null)
            {
              cmb.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
              cmb.DisplayMember = "Grd";
              cmb.ValueMember = "ID";

              if(cmb.Items.Count > 0) 
                cmb.SelectedIndex = 0;
             }
    }
```

Comment: Sir, I tried as per your answer but getting error in `dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing()` that Unable to cast object of type `DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl` to type `ComboBox`

Comment: aah yeah - sry, my cast was wrong. not every cell contains a combobox. Now it will just return null instead of throwing an error. try it.

Comment: Sir, I tried your updated answer, programs gives no error but the records are not fetched from the data set. I debugged the program and it shows that control does not go in `dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit()` @JensKloster